# Using * to parse through files. Need to write file names

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, command-prompt

I have the following problem using UNIX Commands. I wish to go through a large number of files and convert them using a command that converts them. My idea is to work like this: `command *.fileending > *.newfileending`

The problem is that *I wish to keep the file-names and only replace the file-ending*. Thus `filename.fileending` should become `filename.newfileending`. **How do I achieve this?**

Comment: How exactly does the command work? Maybe it already provides a function to write to a new file.

Comment: It works like this: **hum2mid FileName.fileending -o NewFileName.newfileending**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a for loop:

```
for file in *.krn; do
  hum2mid "$file" -o "${file%.krn}.mid"
done
```

In a single line: `for file in *.krn; do hum2mid "$file" -o "${file%.krn}.mid"; done`

---

To apply the command to files and subdirectories recursively, use the `find|xargs` pattern:

```
find -type f -name '*.krn' -print0 \
  | xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'hum2mid "$1" -o "/destination/dir/$(basename ${1%.krn}.mid)"' -
```

Note that this will overwrite already converted files, if a file from another directory has the same name.

Comment: I tried to execute following command **for file in *.krn; do  hum2mid "$file" -o "${file%.krn}.mid" done** (Wrote on single line) but nothing happens when I hit Enter.

Comment: **Thanks!** Now it works. One more question. I wish to process a big number of files in different folders and put the .mid files in one single new folder. How do I achieve this?

Comment: For different folders you have to resort to a solution involving find+xargs, I guess. For storing in a single directory, use an absolute path and append the new filename.

Comment: If we look at accessing different folders. I have looked at **find /essen/america -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ...** but do not know how to continue from there. What should I write?

Comment: I tried the following **find -type f -name '*.krn' -print0 \ | xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'hum2mid "$1" -o /GermMidi/"${1%.krn}.mid"'** It returned this error. **find: search paths must come before expressions ... ...Error: could not open file** I was positioned at a folder with .krn-files. I had created the GermMidi folder before.

Comment: @MichaelWard: You are missing the leading hyphen (`-`) after the shell command (I don't see it in your command). It is significant and must be the first parameter to `sh -c`

Comment: True. But I tried with that as well when I looked for my error. Could it perhaps be that I write the code in one line? I don't know how to write in several lines. Enter will execute the code. I should be positioned in the folder I wish to run the command on? And the folder should have been created before-hand?

Comment: You should be able to paste my command as is into your console (including line breaks, that's why I put the backslash there), it should still work in a single line though, given that you have a whitespace character after the backslash. And yes, the destination folder must already exist and have sufficient permissions (`/GermMidi` is likely to not work, since it is located directly at your filesystem's root)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8509/discussion-between-knittl-and-michael-ward)

Answer (score 0):

```
rename .fileending .newfileending *
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't really get it. How will I use my command that changes the content with this solution? I was perhaps a little unclear. It's not only that I wish to rename them. I wish that the command can be executed on them as well first..

Comment: `rename (1)` uses a different syntax.

Comment: It says that the commando rename does not exist. Perhaps because I'm working in cygwin?

Comment: I verified the command in OpenSuSE 11.x before posting my answer.  It uses `rename` from `util-linux-ng` v2.16

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -1 *.fileending  | while read i; do
  command "$i" > "${i/%.fileending/.newfileending}"
done
```

if you need process 'weird' filenames ( like with embedded '\n', for example ), you can use following trick:

create file `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
command "$1" > "${1/%.fileending/.newfileending}"
```

, then do `chmod +x foo.sh` and finally `find . -maxdepth 1 -a -type f -a -name '*.fileending' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -J '%' ./foo.sh "%"`

Comment: Sure, if you have such files you can use `find -print0` with `xargs -0`. Has update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! The above mentioned answer by knittl worked so I used that